# "Class not registered" error when opening recordset using VB6

Tags: sql-server, vb6, ado

I started getting this problem recently. Don't know how it started but I know I disabled some windows services that startup, and deleted some odbc, probably a mysql odbc data source but I'm using MS SQL 2000 for the following.

I get the error when trying to populate the recordset, and the error details are:
*"Run-time error '-2147221164 (80040154)': Class not registered."*

```
Private Sub cmdTestConnection_Click()
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Initial Catalog=dbname;Data Source=mrtestpc2\sql2000pwd;Extended Properties=uid=sa;pwd=passwordhere;"
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
conn.Open
rs.Open "select * from tablename", conn 'ERROR here
MsgBox CStr(rs.RecordCount)
End Sub
```

The references that might be relevant to this issue which I have ticked is:
Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library

I've tried with different versions with the above reference, from 2.8 to 2.5 but still get the same problem.

EDIT: I'm trying to figure out whether it's an MDAC issue.
EDIT: I'm running windows xp sp3.

Comment: Are you saying you get the error immediately? Or do you know which line of code is causing the error?

Comment: The error occurs when trying to populate the recordset (rs.Open...)

Comment: You might want to start with the MDAC Component Checker. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1953

Comment: I've already downloaded it, it says I have mdac 2.8 SP1 on windows xp sp3.

Comment: Click on the **COM Details** in the left pane and carefully read through the details in the right pane looking for problems. Another option is restoring if you have a recent restore point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running Windows 7 SP1? Microsoft caused that problem with some changes. See the following [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2011/10/03/yes-we-made-a-mistake-and-are-finally-going-to-fix-it.aspx).