# Error -2147221164 Class Not Registered when calling recordset.Open() on Windows 8.1 64-bit

Tags: vb6, windows-8.1, 32bit-64bit

I am receiving error `-2147221164 Class Not Registered` when I execute the following code on a Windows 8.1 64-bit machine:

```
Dim conn as ADODB.Connection
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection 
conn.Open dbConnectionString

Dim rsHere as ADODB.Recordset
Set rsHere = New ADODB.Recordset

' Error happens at this line
rsHere.Open strSql, conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
```

The code was compiled on a Windows XP machine, so I don't think it's the same issue as the one outlined here:

["Class not registered" error when opening recordset using VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095621/class-not-registered-error-when-opening-recordset-using-vb6)

The version of ADODB that I found in the registry is 6.0, while the one I'm using is 2.8. I scoured the web and read somewhere that there was a breaking change made to ADODB on Windows 8, but I'm not sure if this is what is causing my issue.

Does anyone have an idea of what I might check for to eliminate this error?

Comment: It is almost surely the same issue.  Double-check with SysInternals' Process Monitor.

Comment: I used the Process Monitor and tracked it down to a few registry calls that weren't successful. They had to do with ADO.NET 6.0. Unfortunately, having this knowledge does not get me any closer to solving the problem as I don't know what those registry entries are supposed to be.

Comment: The most telling error was this one: RegOpenKey HKLM\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WindowsRuntime\CLSID\{00000542-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4} NAME NOT FOUND Desired Access: Read - That CLSID maps to ADODB 6.0 on the Windows 8.1 machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem when compiling for different versions of Windows from XP machines.  [This may clarify some things](http://blogs.technet.com/b/asiasupp/archive/2011/03/14/changes-in-mdac-adodb-com-components-in-windows-7-service-pack-1.aspx).

From the page (quoting a Microsoft KB article):

> "Some ADO APIs are platform dependent in ADO 2.7 and later versions"

You can also find some more details [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2517589/en-us), in the "Cause" section.

As a workaround, you can try late-binding ADO calls.  In my case, compiling on a Windows 7 SP1 machine did the trick.

Comment: I was afraid of the answer. We are using ancient Component One custom controls and the installer for those doesn't run on Windows 7. I can't get our application to build on a Windows 7 machine because of this.

Comment: We actually got the Component One Spread Sheet control installed on a Windows 7 x64 machine.  It's a manual process, it has to be the 32 bit version and the ocx files should be registered with regsvr32. The licence file should be copied to c:\Windows\System (not System32), and the executables (there's an EXE and a DLL for the Spread control) need to reside in C:\Windows\SysWOW64. It's not as hard as it sounds, and it was worth the effort for us.